# Showing different entities in Sonata Admin list view

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I've got this entity, which contains `entityName` property and `entityId` property:

```
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="entityName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $entityName;

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(name="entityId", type="integer")
     */
    private $entityId;
```

Instead of showing this entity using `__toString()` function, I wanted to actually return the entity with name and id. and show that in sonata admin list view.

for now, here is `__toString`:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->entityName . ":" . $this->entityId;
}
```

which should return something like:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $em->getRepository($this->entityName)->find($this->entityId);
}
```

I hope that I've described my problem well.
tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is to use custom list block for sonata.

1. [create a new twig filter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) called `entityFilter`, this filter will convert FQCN of an sonata admin object to a readable route name generated by sonata. like `admin_blablabla_show`:

   ```
   public function entityFilter($entityName)
   {
       $str = str_replace('\\', '_', $entityName);
       $str = str_replace('Bundle', '', $str);
       $str = str_replace('_Entity', '', $str);
       $str = 'Admin' . $str . '_Show';
       return strtolower($str);
   }

   public function getName()
   {
       return 'my_extension';
   }
   ```
2. in you admin class, set the template of the desired field to a new twig template:

   ```
       ->add('orderItems', null, array(
           'template' => 'AcmeBundle::order_items_list.html.twig'
       ))
   ```
3. And in your new twig template (order_items_list.html.twig):

   ```
   {% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}
   {% block field %}
   <div>
       {% for item in object.orderItems %}
           {% if entity(item.entityName) == 'admin_first_entity_show' %}
               {% set foo = 'Apple ID' %}
           {% elseif entity(item.entityName) == 'admin_second_entity_show' %}
               {% set foo = 'Device Accessory' %}
           {% else %}
               {% set foo = 'Not defiend' %}
           {% endif %}

           <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="{{ path(entity(item.entityName), {'id': item.entityId}) }}"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> {{ foo }}</a>
       {% endfor %}
   </div>
   {% endblock %}
   ```